# Terraform , AWS RDS aurora mysql serverless exception "source cluster could not be found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create one new cluster and another cluster by restore point in time referencing the 1st cluster.
For the 1st tfvar block - It will create a new aurora mysql cluster aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless
In the 2nd tfvar block - It should create a new cluster aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-clone from source aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless. But getting exception "source cluster could not be found or cannot be accessed: aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless" even if it has created cluster.

Below is my structure.

**Main block calling module**

```
module "aurora_mysql" {
  count                                   = var.general_config.cluster_count
  source                                  = "./modules/aurora_mysql"
  cluster_identifier                      = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].cluster_identifier
  source_cluster_identifier               = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].source_cluster_identifier
  engine                                  = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].engine
  engine_version                          = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].engine_version
  engine_mode                             = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].engine_mode
  availability_zones                      = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].availability_zones
  database_name                           = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].database_name
  db_port                                 = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].db_port
  master_username                         = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].master_username
  master_password                         = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].master_password
  backup_retention_period                 = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].backup_retention_period
  restore                                 = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].restore
  restore_type                            = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].restore_type
  db_subnet_group_name                    = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].db_subnet_group_name
  vpc_security_group_ids                  = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].vpc_security_group_ids
  cluster_parameter_group                 = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].cluster_parameter_group
  backtrack_window                        = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].backtrack_window
  skip_final_snapshot                     = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection                     = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].deletion_protection
  db_parameter_group                      = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].db_parameter_group
  auto_pause                              = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].auto_pause
  max_capacity                            = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].max_capacity
  min_capacity                            = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].min_capacity
  seconds_until_auto_pause                = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].seconds_until_auto_pause
  timeout_action                          = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].timeout_action
}
```

**Module variable file**

```
variable "general_config" {
  description                                  = "general configs for tf module."
  type                                         = map
  default                                      = {
    account_id                                 = ""
    aws_region                                 = "us-east-1"
    cluster_count                              = 2
  }
}

variable "aurora_mysql" {
  type = list(object({
     cluster_identifier                        = string
     source_cluster_identifier                 = string
     cluster_parameter_group                   = string
     db_parameter_group                        = string
     engine                                    = string
     engine_version                            = string
     engine_mode                               = string
     database_name                             = string
     db_port                                   = number
     master_username                           = string
     master_password                           = string
     db_subnet_group_name                      = string
     availability_zones                        = list(string)
     vpc_security_group_ids                    = list(string)
     backup_retention_period                   = number
     restore                                   = bool
     restore_type                              = string
     backtrack_window                          = number
     deletion_protection                       = bool
     skip_final_snapshot                       = bool
     auto_pause                                = bool
     max_capacity                              = number
     min_capacity                              = number
     seconds_until_auto_pause                  = number
     timeout_action                            = string
  }))
}
```

**Tfvars file**

```
general_config = {
  account_id        = "accountnumber"         
  aws_region        = "us-east-1"            
  cluster_count     = 2
}

aurora_mysql = [
    {
                cluster_identifier               = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless"                     
                source_cluster_identifier        = ""                                                            
                cluster_parameter_group          = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-cluster-parameter-group"     
                db_parameter_group               = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-db-parameter-group"                                                          
                engine                           = "aurora-mysql"                             
                engine_version                   = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1"                  
                engine_mode                      = "serverless"                              
                database_name                    = "auroramysqlserverless"                              
                db_port                          = 3306                                       
                master_username                  = "admin"                                    
                master_password                  = "admin1234"                                               
                db_subnet_group_name             = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-subnet-group"                
                availability_zones               = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]               
                vpc_security_group_ids           = ["sg-1234"]                   
                backup_retention_period          = 1                                                                        
                backtrack_window                 = 0                                          
                restore                          = false                                      
                restore_type                     = ""                                                                                                                 
                deletion_protection              = false                                      
                skip_final_snapshot              = true                                       
                auto_pause                       = true                                       
                max_capacity                     = 256                                        
                min_capacity                     = 2                                          
                seconds_until_auto_pause         = 300                                        
                timeout_action                   = "ForceApplyCapacityChange"                 
    },
    {
                cluster_identifier               = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-clone"                     
                source_cluster_identifier        = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless"                                                            
                cluster_parameter_group          = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-clone-cluster-parameter-group"     
                db_parameter_group               = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-clone-db-parameter-group"                                                          
                engine                           = "aurora-mysql"                             
                engine_version                   = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1"                  
                engine_mode                      = "serverless"                              
                database_name                    = "auroramysqlserverless"                              
                db_port                          = 3306                                       
                master_username                  = "admin"                                    
                master_password                  = "admin1234"                                               
                db_subnet_group_name             = "aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless-clone-subnet-group"                
                availability_zones               = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]               
                vpc_security_group_ids           = ["sg-1234"]                   
                backup_retention_period          = 1                                                                        
                backtrack_window                 = 0                                          
                restore                          = true                                      
                restore_type                     = "copy-on-write"                                                                                                                 
                deletion_protection              = false                                      
                skip_final_snapshot              = true                                       
                auto_pause                       = true                                       
                max_capacity                     = 256                                        
                min_capacity                     = 2                                          
                seconds_until_auto_pause         = 300                                        
                timeout_action                   = "ForceApplyCapacityChange"                 
    },
]
```

**Resource to which module calls (rds_mysql)**

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
  cluster_identifier                  = var.cluster_identifier
  engine                              = var.engine
  engine_version                      = var.engine_version
  engine_mode                         = var.engine_mode
  availability_zones                  = var.availability_zones
  database_name                       = var.database_name
  port                                = var.db_port
  master_username                     = var.master_username
  master_password                     = var.master_password
  backup_retention_period             = var.backup_retention_period
  db_subnet_group_name                = var.db_subnet_group_name
  vpc_security_group_ids              = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name     = var.cluster_parameter_group
  backtrack_window                    = var.backtrack_window
  skip_final_snapshot                 = var.skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection                 = var.deletion_protection

  dynamic "restore_to_point_in_time" {
    for_each = var.restore == true ? [1] : []
    content {
      source_cluster_identifier         = var.source_cluster_identifier
      restore_type                      = var.restore_type
      use_latest_restorable_time        = true
    }
  }

  dynamic "scaling_configuration" {
      auto_pause                        = var.auto_pause
      max_capacity                      = var.max_capacity
      min_capacity                      = var.min_capacity
      seconds_until_auto_pause          = var.seconds_until_auto_pause
      timeout_action                    = var.timeout_action
  }


  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy             = false
    ignore_changes = [
     availability_zones
    ]
  }
}
```

**Resource variables**

```
variable "cluster_identifier" {
  description = "The name of the RDS instance. If the value is empty, Terraform assigns a random unique identifier."
  type        = string
}

variable "source_cluster_identifier" {
  description = "The name of the RDS instance. If the value is empty, Terraform assigns a random unique identifier."
  type        = string
}

variable "cluster_parameter_group" {
  description = "cluster parameter group name"
  type        = string
}

variable "cluster_parameter_group_family" {
  description = "cluster parameter group family name"
  type        = string
}


variable "db_parameter_group" {
  description = "db parameter group name"
  type        = string
}


variable "engine" {
  description = "rds_aurora mysql"
  type        = string
}

variable "engine_version" {
  description = "postgres version"
  type        = string
}

variable "engine_mode" {
  description = " version"
  type        = string
  default     = "provisioned"
}

variable "database_name" {
  description = "The DB name to create. If omitted, no database is created initially"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "db_port" {
  description = "database port"
  type        = number
  default     = 3306
}

variable "master_username" {
  description = "RDS root user"
}

variable "master_password" {
  description = "RDS root user password"
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "availability_zones" {
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "backup_retention_period" {
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource"
  type        = number
}


variable "db_subnet_group_name" {
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource"
  type        = string
}

variable "db_parameter_group_family" {
  description = "parameter_group_family"
  type        = string
}

variable "backtrack_window" {
  description = "Defaults to 0. Must be between 0 and 259200 (72 hours)"
  type        = number
  default     = 0
}

variable "deletion_protection" {
  description = "If the DB instance should have deletion protection enabled.The database can't be deleted when this value is set to true. The default is false"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "skip_final_snapshot" {
  description = "Determines whether a final DB snapshot is created before the DB cluster is deleted. If true is specified, no DB snapshot is created. If false is specified, a DB snapshot is created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "restore_type" {
  description = "(Optional) Type of restore to be performed. Valid options are full-copy (default) and copy-on-write."
  type        = string
}

variable "restore" {
  description             = "only if you want to restore from existing instance"
  type                    = bool
  default                 = false
}

variable "auto_pause" {
  description             = "Whether to enable automatic pause. A DB cluster can be paused only when it's idle (it has no connections). If a DB cluster is paused for more than seven days, the DB cluster might be backed up with a snapshot. In this case, the DB cluster is restored when there is a request to connect to it. Defaults to true."
  type                    = bool
  default                 = true
}

variable "max_capacity" {
  description             = "The maximum capacity for an Aurora DB cluster in serverless DB engine mode. The maximum capacity must be greater than or equal to the minimum capacity. Valid Aurora MySQL capacity values are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256. Valid Aurora PostgreSQL capacity values are (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 192, and 384). Defaults to 16."
  type                    = number
  default                 = 16
}

variable "min_capacity" {
  description             = "The minimum capacity for an Aurora DB cluster in serverless DB engine mode. The minimum capacity must be lesser than or equal to the maximum capacity. Valid Aurora MySQL capacity values are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256. Valid Aurora PostgreSQL capacity values are (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 192, and 384). Defaults to 1"
  type                    = number
  default                 = 1
}

variable "seconds_until_auto_pause" {
  description             = "The time, in seconds, before an Aurora DB cluster in serverless mode is paused. Valid values are 300 through 86400. Defaults to 300."
  type                    = number
  default                 = 300
}

variable "timeout_action" {
  description             = "The action to take when the timeout is reached. Valid values: ForceApplyCapacityChange, RollbackCapacityChange. Defaults to RollbackCapacityChange"
  type                    = string
  default                 = "RollbackCapacityChange"
}
```

**Issue:**
Getting below exception while terraform is trying to create cluster referencing the 1st cluster.
kindly advise in fixing below issue.

```
module.aurora_mysql[0].aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql: Still creating... [6m0s elapsed]
module.aurora_mysql[0].aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql: Creation complete after 6m6s [id=aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless]
╷
│ Error: DBClusterNotFoundFault: The source cluster could not be found or cannot be accessed: aurora-cluster-mysql-serverless
│       status code: 404, request id: 31950839-5ca6-433f-acf8-e4b3d8089dd3
│
│   with module.aurora_mysql[1].aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql,
│   on modules/aurora_mysql/aurora_mysql.tf line 36, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql":
│   36: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
│
╵
```

Comment: No still facing the issue , sorry for the delay , I have updated the full code.

Comment: Hi Marcin, did you found anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this, you can create one cluster in one module and restore point in time in another module. You can achieve what you want this way.

Comment: It is giving same error , even multiple modules are created concurrently in terraform

Comment: Working on adding dependency for the modules. :)

Answer (score 4):

Sadly you can't do this. If you are creating clusters with `count`:

```
 count                                   = 2
```

TF will create two clusters **concurrently**. Thus obviously the second cluster fails, because the first cluster does not exist, because its being created alongside (not before) the second one. You have to create two clusters separately.

Comment: but it says it has created cluste "raurora-cluster-mysql-2"  in below line.                                                "Creation complete after 6m6s [id=aurora-cluster-mysql-2]" .                                                            Also their isn't any sleep option which we can add to delay it ?

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki It would be good if you updated your question with full, working example demonstrating your issue. Something that anyone can copy-and-paste and replicate your issue.